# Bootstrap Progress Bar Not Loading Progression

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to link the progress bar to my SQLite3 database column to show how far each individual has made it through the interview process. I've replaced the width with my column in my database that shows their step in the process (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5) but the bar shows blank for everyone.

Why would this not work?

pick_list.html

```
<tr id="{{ pick.pk }}">
    <td><img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/files/{{ pick.photo }}" width="50"/></td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'app:lead-list' pick.pk %}" title="Leads">{{ pick.name }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ pick.hometown }}</td>
    <td>{{ pick.occupation }}</td>
    <td>{{ pick.age }}</td>
    <td>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="{{ pick.step }}"></div>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-sm border-0 reorder" title="Reorder">
            <i class="fa fa-sort text-secondary"></i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

model

```
class Pick(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Name', null=True, blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="media", max_length=500, verbose_name='Photo', null=True, blank=True)
    hometown = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Hometown', null=True, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Age', null=True, blank=True)
    step = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Progress', null=True, blank=True)    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Occupation', null=True, blank=True)
    rank = OrderField(verbose_name='Rank', null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_fields(self):
        return [(field.verbose_name, field.value_from_object(self)) for field in self.__class__._meta.fields]
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('app:pick-update', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'pick'
        ordering = ['rank']
        verbose_name = 'Pick'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Picks'
```

views.py

```
class PickList(LoginRequiredMixin, CoreListView):
    model = Pick

'''
    def user_picks(request):
        Pick.objects.filter(submitter='rwcg2d')
        return render(request, 'app/pick_list.html', {'Pick': Pick})
'''
class PickCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, AjaxCreateView):
    model = Pick
    form_class = PickForm

    # def get_redirect_url(self):
    #     return reverse_lazy('app:home')


class PickUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, AjaxUpdateView):
    model = Pick
    form_class = PickForm

class PickDelete(LoginRequiredMixin, AjaxDeleteView):
    model = Pick

class PickDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, AjaxDetailView):
    model = Pick
    # form_class = PickForm
```

Comment: Try setting the value to populate aria-valuenow="{{ pick.step}}" instead of style.

Comment: And could you include the views.py file?

Comment: No luck with the valuenow update and I loaded the views.py

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to come from setting style attribute to a value i.e `style="{{ pick.step }}"` instead of something like `style="width: 75%"`. You need to calculate the percentage and pass it accordingly

Comment: So you're saying that it's a type issue, e.g. im passing an integer when I need a percentage? Wouldn't it just default a value of 5 to 500% and make the bar full?

Comment: You need to explicitly put the % sign also it's supposed to `style="width: 75%"` not `style="75"` or  `style="75%"`